# Reusable TableViewCell in Interface Builder WITH changeable labels?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, cell, tableview, uitableview

How do I make a reusable TableViewCell in Interface Builder with changeable labels?

Is this even possible? From what I understand apple has been giving custom TableViewCell in Interface Builder some love lately, so this should be possible?

Ps. I know there are a lot of questions with answers about TableViewCell in IB, but I couldn't find anyone that made labels work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change anything in a cell that is being re-used. To customize labels that you create in IB, you should set their tags in IB itself & fetch the label using the same tag.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    // Configure the cell.
    //Do anything here with the labels. Even add or remove them.
    (UILabel*) label1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: No I meant if I create a custom cell in IB.. how do I get references to the labels I put there.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it he same way as in accepted answer, but I've always felt  using tags like I'm using "go to" in Pascal. Feels dirty. But maybe it's just me, tags work just fine.

There's an alternative way though. Subclass a UITableViewCell, create an IBOutlet property, connect in IB, and reference your property in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code. Like so:

```
interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *myAwesomeLabel;

@end
```

Don't forget to set you cell's class to MyCustomCell in IB.

[image]

After that you can connect your property in IB directly like so

[image]

And in your Table View Data Source now you can access this property

```
#import "MyCustomCell.h"


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell) {
        cell.myAwesomeLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Using tags is error-prone and might turn into a mess very quickly if you use a lot of them.